# Multithreading, can't run Process command

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import multiprocessing

def f(name): 
print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

The output I get is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 9, in <module>
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Process'
```

Comment: Did you name the script multiprocessing.py? If so, rename it.

Comment: Maybe you can check if you can import multiprocessing from Python shell by entering `import multiprocessing`

Comment: Even if you have `multiprocessing.py` as any file name in the parent directory you'll get the error

Comment: >>import multiprocessing
it works!
>>from multiprocessing import Process
ImportError: cannot import name Process

This is what I get..any clue?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your error. The problem must be that you have some other module named `multiprocessing` in your directory where the file `a.py` is located

Comment: After importing it on shell see what output `help(multiprocessing)` gives. If it does not give the original multiprocessing docstring then you are importing some other script.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: >>from multiprocessing import Process
ImportError: cannot import name Process
This is what I get once I type this command in python shell

Comment: @MattPennington python 2.7.3

Comment: @MuhammadSuleman List all the files in the directory where `a.py` is stored

Comment: @zamk 
>>import multiprocessing
it imports!
>>from multiprocessing import Process
It states:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Process

Comment: @zamk 
{ >>import multiprocessing
>>help(multiprocessing)
it only states the multi() function is available!
I am running python 2.7.3.. that is due to the compiler version i am using?

Comment: @BhargavRao following are the files located in 'a.py' directory

a.py            h.txt                q         try.py
Desktop         lock.py              queue.py  vmware-tools-distrib
dirfinder.py    lock.pyc             sock.py
ftp.py          multiprocessing.pyc  s.txt
HelloWorld1.py  Practice             sul.txt

Comment: @MuhammadSuleman  Delete that multiprocessing.pyc and try again

Comment: @BhargavRao I just deleted multiprocessing.pyc.. and its working!!!
thanks a bunch for highlighting.. any idea why it wasnt working?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are trying to `import multiprocessing` from your local directory and not from the python library. The python interpreter first tries to import the module from the present directory. As you have got a file with the name `multiprocessing.pyc` in your directory, the interpreter is trying to import that. Hence you have got the error. Thus deleting `multiprocessing.pyc` will help resolve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

Dont give the name of the file as "multiprocessing.py", give any other

thanks,
vybhav

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was naming, my script as 'multiprocessing.py', once it was created. I made an another script with name 'a.py' and both of them were not working. After listing the directories, 'multiprocessing.pyc'  was located. I deleted this file, and executed 'a.py' file which executed like gem!
thanks to @Bhargav Rao for highlighting

Answer (score 0):

Don't give the name in the same directory as multiprocess.py, use different name instead.